# Bulk read from mongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, performance, mongodb-query

I have simple query (without any where clause). It returns around 150K documents each document has around 5 fields. To get all the records in JSON array format, it takes around 5-6 seconds. This performance is okay with single request, but my code is running inside a Java RESTful service. If I send 10-15 requests then performance degrades, now it takes more than a minute to get the response.

On investigation, I set the batch size with the find query to 5000. With this there is improvement by 50% but it still not acceptable.

I am using MongoDB 3.4.4 with Java driver.

Following is the code snippet.

```
    BasicDBObject attributes = new BasicDBObject();
    attributes.put("att1", 1);
    attributes.put("att2", 1);
    attributes.put("att3", 1);
    attributes.put("att4", 1);
    attributes.put("att5", 1);
    attributes.put("att6", 1);
    attributes.put("_id", 0);

    FindIterable<BsonDocument> dbResult = db.getCollection("mycollection", BsonDocument.class).find().batchSize(1000)
            .projection(attributes);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("[");

    for (BsonDocument d : dbResult) {
        sb.append(d.toString());
        sb.append(",");
    }

    String result = sb.substring(0, sb.lastIndexOf(",")) + "]";

    JsonParser parser = new JsonParser();
    JsonArray jsonObject = (JsonArray) parser.parse(result);
```

I have following questions.

1. How to find the optimized batch size.
2. In MongoDB APIs I could not find anyway to get bulk data, I could only see the Find method which can return cursor, I have to iterate over all the documents one by one. Is there any way I can do the bulk read.
3. With one request performance is good, why performance degrades heavily if I make concurrent requests? Is there any other way/parameter which can optimize the performance for me.

Annu

Comment: Are these requests loading the same 150K records? If not, they will compete for cache space and probably cause a lot of disk I/O.

Comment: Setting `batchSize` is as good as you are going to get without [*"getting a bigger boat"*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=We%27re%20Gonna%20Need%20a%20Bigger%20Boat). This mostly comes down to hardware and nework capabilities, so if you want to throw big numbers out there, then you have to be serious. And running on something not capable of your expected results is not being serious. The only other practical things to do are to split your requests and write out "ranges" of data instead. But it's all very much a variation on general scaling themes.

Comment: @Thilo - My current test is returning all the same 150K records with each request. But I want my program to handle both the cases where mongo DB query returns same or different number of records. Just wondering does it really matters?

Comment: Please state the hardware mongodb runs on. RAM, CPU, spinning disks or SSDs? OS? Other processes on the machine MongoDB runs on?